# Глобальные переменные webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Структура js файла

```
var test = 123;
require ('./custom/components/buttons.js');
require ('./custom/components/fixed-buttons.js');
require ('./custom/components/tabs.js');
require ('./custom/components/accordions.js');
require ('./custom/components/sliders');
```

Затем если перейти в sliders.js и сделать console.log, то будет такая ошибка:

sliders.js:296 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at Object.434 (sliders.js:296)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 5dd9c166f83054f151df:54)
    at Object.171 (main.js:15)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 5dd9c166f83054f151df:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 5dd9c166f83054f151df:25)
    at main.js?v=1545639314088:1

Comment: Нужно сделать экспорт переменной test и импортировать в sliders.js

Comment: Создал отдельно файл vendor.js, а в main.js написал
import test from './vendor' и ничего не произошло. В консоли пустые скобки без значения {}

Comment: а в vendor.js так сделали: `export var test = 123;` ?

Comment: Получилось, но сделал так. Обязательно var писать?
exports.test = 123;

Comment: `export var test = 123;` - ES6 инструкция экспорта, а `exports.test = 123;` экспорт CommonJS. Если вы пишите код согласно ES6, то первый вариант, если нет, то делайте экспорт вторым вариантом.

Comment: написал exports.test = 123  получил объект {test: 123}. Как мне просто значение получить?

Comment: `exports` это объект, и устанавливаете ему свойство `test`: `import {test} from './vendor'`

Попробуйте `exports = test;` и `var test = require ('./custom/components/vendor');`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Всё получилось. Можете опубликовать ответ на основе ваших комментариев и добавить полезные ссылки по webpack для новичка?

Comment: Конечно, ответ, если есть в нем необходимость, опубликую чуть позже.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В контексте вопроса: для использования переменной в `test` в другом модуле(файле) можно использовать [экспорт](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) и [импорт](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) согласно спецификации ES-2015:

```
//globals.js
export const test = 123;

//main.js
import { test } from 'globals'
```

Или используем ключевое слово default для экспорта только одного значения(фигурные скобки не нужны):

```
//globals.js
const test = 123;
export default test;

//main.js
import test from 'globals'
```

Рекомендую в данном случае использовать Webpack в сочетании с транспилятором [babel](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/babel-webpack/).

Webpack также предлагает способ в синтаксисе CommonJS, который Вы использовали. 
Знакомо будет тем, кто работал с NodeJS:

```
//globals.js
var test = 123;
module.exports = test;

//main.js
var test = require('globals');
```

При том, Вы можете использовать оба варианта одновременно.
Более подробно о всех способах подключения модулей [здесь](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/).

Если же необходимо экспортировать переменную в глобальную область после сборки проекта, то это выглядит примерно так:

```
//Более простой способ
//index.js
function App() {}
window.App = App;
```

или

```
//index.js
export default function App() {}

//Указываем в конфиге
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        library: 'App',
        libraryTarget: 'window',
        libraryExport: 'default'
        ...
    }
    ...    
}
```